# Move Shape with KineticJS

Tags: javascript, canvas, kineticjs

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HZPSU/4/), with a shape that should be moved on mouse drag events. I can see in the javascript console that shape.move() is called with proper values, the shape wouldn't move though.

Why doesn't the shape move?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After `stage.draw()` is called, the shape moves.